# Which countries require inventors to get a permission (e.g., a foreign filing license) to be allowed to file a patent in another country?

Tags: international, filing, foreign

I [read](https://www.lakshmisri.com/newsroom/archives/foreign-filing-license-a-must-know-requirement/#):

> When an inventor or a company, who is a resident in India, desires to file a patent application first in a country other than India, it is necessary to obtain an FFL from the Indian Patent Office.

This makes me wonder: which countries require inventors to get a permission (e.g., a foreign filing license) to be allowed to file a patent in another country?

Comment: My answer was from the google search ”foreign filing license requirements”. The third result.

Answer (score 2):

Many countries have some similar requirement. The WIPO lists [34 member states](https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/texts/nat_sec.html) with some foreign filing rules.

Some require it if the inventing was done in their country, others have rules for residents/citizens regardless of where the inventing occurred. Some only limit filings that contain “state secrets”. The linked table at the WIPO has a summary.

The U.S. requires a foreign filing license if the inventing was done in the US. Most countries provide a default of a license upon filing locally. That is, unless you hear otherwise within a set time frame you have a license. To file first non-locally you need to explicitly request a license.